# GPU Module equivalent to glDepthRange

Tags: python, gpu-module

I'm working to change my drawing code over from bgl calls to Blender's GPU module (as bgl calls are set to be depreciated) and can't seem to find an equivalent to the bgl.glDepthRange function in the docs.

The drawing code I'm using needs to be drawn as layers, so I'm currently using these simple bgl calls:

```
bgl.glDepthMask(bgl.GL_TRUE)
bgl.glDepthRange(EDGE_DEPTH[0], EDGE_DEPTH[1])
batch.draw(shader)
```

I do the same for other elements and it layers them correctly when drawing.

I'm working with 2D coordinates and I'm hoping not to have to start adding in a z component to make this work. Is there a way to set drawing depths with the GPU module? I can see the gpu.state.depth_test_set and gpu.state.depth_mask_set functions in the docs but no way to set the depth range.

Comment: I don't see an equivalent either. Just a thought: maybe you can tweak the [z translation of the GPU matrix](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.matrix.html#gpu.matrix.translate) and keep the drawing in 2D?

Comment: I've just had a go at this and can't seem to get it working. It's a shame because it seems like it's the right way to approach this. I'm not sure if gpu.state.clip_distances_set, gpu.state.depth_mask_set and gpu.state.depth_test_set need to be used to make it work but all the combinations I've tried have failed.